# how can i cycle trough a bunch of buttons to reduce the code?

Tags: android

hi
I have this code where i need to tho the same operation on different object of the same type,like initialize a bunch of buttons and setting every time the value of the text, now my code looks like this:

```
 public void inizializzazioneGrafica(){
    txtprimaCarta = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_primaCarta);
    punteggioG1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggioG1);
    punteggioG2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggioG2);
    btn_g1_1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_g1_1);
    btn_g1_2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_g1_2);
    btn_g1_3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_g1_3);
    btn_g2_1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_g2_1);
    btn_g2_2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_g2_2);
    btn_g2_3 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_g2_3);
}
public void aggiornaGrafica(){
    txtprimaCarta.setText(Integer.toString(tavolo.getBriscola().getNumero())+"\n"+tavolo.getBriscola().getSeme().toString());
    punteggioG1.setText("Punteggio: "+Integer.toString(giocatore1.getPunteggio()));
    punteggioG2.setText("Punteggio: "+Integer.toString(giocatore2.getPunteggio()));
    btn_g1_1.setText(Integer.toString(giocatore1.carte.get(0).getNumero())+" "+giocatore1.carte.get(0).getSeme().toString());
    btn_g1_2.setText(Integer.toString(giocatore1.carte.get(1).getNumero())+" "+giocatore1.carte.get(1).getSeme().toString());
    btn_g1_3.setText(Integer.toString(giocatore1.carte.get(2).getNumero())+" "+giocatore1.carte.get(2).getSeme().toString());
    btn_g2_1.setText(Integer.toString(giocatore2.carte.get(0).getNumero())+" "+giocatore2.carte.get(0).getSeme().toString());
    btn_g2_2.setText(Integer.toString(giocatore2.carte.get(1).getNumero())+" "+giocatore2.carte.get(1).getSeme().toString());
    btn_g2_3.setText(Integer.toString(giocatore2.carte.get(2).getNumero())+" "+giocatore2.carte.get(2).getSeme().toString());
    btn_g1_1.setBottom(Color.LTGRAY);
    btn_g1_2.setBottom(Color.LTGRAY);
    btn_g1_3.setBottom(Color.LTGRAY);
    btn_g2_1.setBottom(Color.LTGRAY);
    btn_g2_2.setBottom(Color.LTGRAY);
    btn_g2_3.setBottom(Color.LTGRAY);
}
```

what can i do to reduce the lines of code?
I thought maybe using a for cycle but i dont know how to call the different buttons every time since they have an unique name, can someone help me with this?

Comment: You can try Kotlin and reduce the amount of boilerplate code you need to write.

Comment: and with java how can i do it?

Comment: I don't see any easier way to achieve what you are doing. You can probably create some collections where you group buttons based on similar properties and then you can loop through the collections. That might shorten your code but it would have no other benefits. And when you'll add a new button, or want to change a property of a button then you will need to do some refactoring. So there is no benefits at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce code used for binding view (in your `inizializzazioneGrafica` method) , you can use [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) library. Your code will be something like this :

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
  @BindView(R.id.txt_primaCarta) TextView txtprimaCarta;
  @BindView(R.id.punteggioG1) TextView punteggioG1;
  @BindView(R.id.btn_g1_1) Button btn_g1_1;
  @BindView(R.id.btn_g1_2) Button btn_g1_2;
  @BindView(R.id.btn_g1_3) Button btn_g1_3;
  @BindView(R.id.btn_g2_1) Button btn_g2_1;
  @BindView(R.id.btn_g2_2) Button btn_g2_2;
  @BindView(R.id.btn_g2_3) Button btn_g2_3;

   ...

  public void aggiornaGrafica(){
    ...
  }
}
```

To simplify your `aggiornaGrafica` you can use 2-dimensional Array or List (like ArrayList) but it won't give you anything but complexity in your code. Strive for effectiveness not efficiency.